# PHP table based on month and date

Tags: php, date

i want make a table than can be input with existing data, and also the table already exist even before the data inputted,table created based on how many days in this month(i.e: right now is october so it have 31 tables since october have 31 days).

The question are i want to put date number in column date and days in column days, basically `date =1` so `days of week=saturday`, `date =2` so `days of week=sunday`(based on current calendar) and so on

i not quite sure about the logic, cause every time i tried, it only fill the first `div` or its fill the whole `div`check out my code below
[image]

> CODE

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Action</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Day of Week</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Location</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Brief Description of Activity </th>
            <th  colspan="6"><center>Project Code & Hour Worked</center> </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>Hours Worked</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>Hours Worked</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>Hours Worked</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
       $start  = new DateTime('first day of this month');
       $end    = new DateTime('first day of this month + 1 month');
       $period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
       for($i= 1; $i < date('t') + 1; $i++){
          for($j =1;$j<=1;$j++){
          echo "<td><a href='#modal-dialog' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-toggle='modal'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span>i=".$i."</td>".PHP_EOL;
           }
          for($j =2;$j<=2;$j++){
             foreach($period as $day){
                echo "<td>".$day->format('M-d')."</td>".PHP_EOL;
             }
          for($j =1;$j<11;$j++){
             echo "<td></td>".PHP_EOL;;
          }
       echo "</tr>";
       }
    ?>                                    
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You loop through the days and build the columns. Your loop through the days should build the rows.

```
 <tbody>
     <?php
       $day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of this month'));
       for($i= 1; $i < date('t') + 1; $i++){
     ?>
     <tr>
      <td><a href='#modal-dialog' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-toggle='modal'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span>i=<?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('M-d',strtotime($day)); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('l',strtotime($day)); ?></td>
       <?php
          for($j =1;$j<=8;$j++){
             echo "<td></td>".PHP_EOL;
          }
       ?>
   </tr>
   <?php 
   $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
 } ?>                                    
</tbody>
```

Comment: dude can u help me with another thing, if i want make all saturday and sunday color being blue, which part should i add?

Comment: You need to check for date('w',strtotime($day)) to be 0 or 6. This will give you those lines you need to color.